# Can I change ID's, names and values within loop

Tags: php, wordpress

i am working in wordpress and little confused.

with the help of loop I created 9 lists but I am not understanding how can I change the value, id and name of each input field.

```
<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tab1_thumb' ); ?>
```

how can i change **tab1_thumb** for each li

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= 9) {
    ?>
    <li style="border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 15px;">
        <p><strong><?php echo 'Tab 0'.$i; ?></strong></p>           
        <p><strong><?php _e('Thumbnail: '); ?></strong><input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tab1_thumb' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'tab1_thumb' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['tab1_thumb']; ?>" class="widefat" /></p>
        <p><strong><?php _e('Featured Image: '); ?></strong><input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tab1_featured' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'tab1_featured' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['tab1_featured']; ?>" class="widefat" /></p>
        <p><strong><?php _e('Category: '); ?></strong> <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('name' => $this->get_field_name('tab1_cat_name'), 'selected' => $instance['tab1_cat_name'], 'orderby' => 'Name' , 'hierarchical' => 1, 'show_option_all' => '', 'hide_empty' => '0', 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat')); ?></label></p>
        <p><strong><?php _e('Description: '); ?></strong><br>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('tab1_description'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('tab1_description'); ?>" type="text"></textarea></p>
    </li>
    <?php
        $i += 1;
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply concatenate the values `'tab'` with `$i` and `'_thumb'`:

```
get_field_id( 'tab'.$i.'_thumb' );
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're wanting to do specifically with creating nine of these list elements, unless you're just testing a layout. Typically generation of list elements in a dynamic fashion is due to data from some sort of a data provider, such as a database. But if you're just trying to generate exactly nine unique list items, this is one way to do so.

Comment: I just want to confirm that can we concatenate in function arguments of not?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you can concatenate in function arguments. Consider the concatenation operator to be a function in of itself - because it is. It being in between two arguments makes it an infix operator. Were it a prefix operator, it would look something like `.(.('tab', $i), '_thumb')`. The use of a function as an argument to a function is called _composition_, and is used in nearly all programming languages.